# How to update transactions in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, angular7, enhanced-ecommerce

I am using the enhanced ecommerce plugin for Google Analytics.

I am using analytics.js to send transactions to Google Analytics.

After completing the transaction means confirming order,user can edit the order and add/remove items.

So we manage this thing in Google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options in GA:

- collecting **refunds** events attached to a transaction, where a full or partial refund can happen. Refunds are different from Revenue: Revenue will remain unchanged, but you get Refunds next to it.
- **revert** completely a transaction by applying a new one with negative values, but I would  recommend to do it only on the same day as the original transaction

**Refunds can be performed through**

- Measurement Protocol calls https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#measuring-refunds (including in Javascript)
- Data Import https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6066862?hl=en either manually of through the API

**Reverting a transaction on the same day**
can be done through Measurement Protocol calls
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en

If you don't revert on the same day, and look at a date range that includes the original transaction but not the negative transaction that reverse it, you will still see the original transaction. 
If you extract daily revenue, same effect: you'll get unaffected revenue on original day AND minored revenue on the day you reverted the transaction. This is not optimal.

But keep in mind that GA isn't your accounting system. And people have the right to block GA tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i want to revert entire transaction not only revenue, tax but also Items List inside specific transaction. Means I want do something like this User place one order say Id is Order123, now when user edit order I want to reflect edit order changes in  GA. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do a partial refund: it will increment refunds but will not change transaction nor product level aggregates: those are frozen. This is how GA balances between being free and being fast.

Answer (score 0):

I tried **refunds** and it did recorded the refunds, but it made no change to amounts recorded!

Then I tried to send multiple transactions (using Google Analytics API and using standard Javascript code) with the same **transaction_id**  hoping it would update the original entry. It did record the secondary transaction, but it was ignored (only the first transaction was is calculated). I also tried to use the original "client_id" (taken from COOKIE "ga"), but it made no difference whatsoever.

**In my opinion there's no way to update the order amount in Analytics**

Unless you would send new transaction_id (for example ORDERNUMBER_001, ORDERNUMBER_002 etc.) with negative amount, but that would cause discrepancies in quantities and order amounts.